# exporting environment variable in makefile from docker doesn't work?

Tags: docker, makefile

I created the following Makefile, if I call docker-test, it will run the docker then calls the makefile build-test target locally.

When I run the docker manually and call the makefile inside the docker it works just fine, the variable `NETDIR` is set correctly, but when I call it from the host, using `make docker-test` the variable `NETDIR` inside docker is defined as `/src` instead of `/usr/app/networker/src`

```
export NETDIR=$(PWD)/src

docker-%:
    docker run --rm -v "$(PWD)":/usr/app/networker -w /usr/app/networker network make $(@:docker-%=build-%)

clean-%:
    cd ./build && $(MAKE) $@


build-%:
    cd ./build && $(MAKE) $@
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your environment variable in the docker run command. Such as

```bash
docker run --rm -v "$(PWD)":/usr/app/networker -e NETDIR -w /usr/app/networker network make $(@:docker-%=build-%)
```

(this will tell the container to inherit `NETDIR` from the parent environment, alternatively you can choose to set a value)